# What can cause istream::getline() to loop on the same line?

Tags: c++, ifstream, text-parsing

I'm reading different .csv files from different sources. I am not creating those files.

At some point when reading these files I need to skip a few lines and use this:

```
void skipLines(unsigned int nLines, std::ifstream& file){
   char l[1024];
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nLines; i++)
      file.getline(l, 1024);
}
```

This worked until now for a certain file.

The file open correctly, then I want to skip the first 5 line and I run `skipLines(5, file)`.

By debugging, I can see that `l` correctly gets the data from the first 4 lines. When reaching the next line (which should have text), it just shows in the debugger as `""`.

If I check the characters which are found in the that line I see the first character is `'\0'` (end of string?), the following characters are the characters that "should" be from the previous line.

If continue to run `skipLines()` on more lines, it keeps looping on the same data. Always `l` with the same set of characters starting with `'\0'`.

What can cause this? And how should I correctly "skip" lines when parsing a text file?

**EDIT:** If the content of the file is copied and pasted to new file and saved. The problem is gone. But that is not a work around I can use in this case.

I don't want to share the exact content of the file, but it basically looks like this:

```
Transfers
User,****,*****

Timestamp,Type,***,Subtotal,Fees,Total,Currency,Price,Payment Method,ID,Share
2017-06-01 10:54:42 -0700,***,0.25638772,50.0,2.00,52.0,***,195.02,***************,***54e27dd1741d3810a8e0,0
```

The line starting with Timestamp is where it loops.

Comment: Can you post the offending file, or a reproduction of it? ([mcve])

Comment: Perhaps the line is empty? How many lines are there in the file? It is a *text* file? Opened in text mode? Can you perhaps show us the input file you use (or at least the six first lines of it)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: If I copy paste the content of the file to a new file, save it, then read it, the problem is gone. I prefer to not share the original file. If the file is opened in an editor, it is nothing but comma separated text.

Comment: Perhaps a line-ending problem? If you look at the file in a hex-editor, are the newlines what you expect them to be?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude opening in Notepad++ shows the correct lines at least..

Comment: @TheDude any insight in how would apply that overload in this case?

Comment: @remi000 Be sure to `ignore()` any line ending characters before applying `std::getline()`,` Also using a fixed buffer doesn't look like a good idea for my taste, rather use a `std::string` variable.

Comment: @TheDude Ok, thanks. So now, just saving by that text file once, the problem was gone. So its some sort of "hidden" characters that cause this? That the text-editor maybe ignores/cancel?

Comment: @remi000 Did you actually read the linked Q&A I've been pointing you to?

Comment: @TheDude I will have a deeper dive in it.

Comment: Perhaps `getline` fails and isn't actually modifying your buffer, which still contains the last read line. You should do some error handling.